# Convert Bash script to AWK script

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, solaris

```bsh
CURTIME=$(date '+%s')
LOG=/home/apache_logs.txt
FILETIME1=$(stat $LOG -c %Y)
TIMEDIFF1=$(expr $CURTIME - $FILETIME1)
```

I created this script in Ubuntu and it works fine there but on SunOS, (Generic_150400-64 sun4v sparc sun4v), it is not working.

This script is to check if logs are updating and do ( If else ) depending on the output of seconds in  TIMEDIFF1 .

If else will perform stuff like, if logs are updated 15 mins ago do this, if 30 mins ago do that... and so on.

So time in seconds as an output is important for if else statement to run efficiently.

so I am trying to determine  how old a file is (how long ago it was modified / updated) in SECONDS. and I need time in seconds.

Comment: What have you already tried? Can you paste your code attempts?

Comment: first four lines where i need modification is already pasted above my question, but ill post here again.

CURTIME=$(nawk "BEGIN{print srand}")

LOG=/home/apache_logs.txt

FILETIME1=$(stat $LOG -c %Y)

TIMEDIFF1=$(expr $CURTIME - $FILETIME1)

Comment: So basically you’re trying to determine how old a file is (how long ago it was modified / updated)?  Do you need to know *exactly* how old it is, or is it OK to get a “yes” or “no” answer to a query like “Was it longer ago than *N* seconds?” (for some value of *N* )? … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to give clearer and more complete description of *the **objective*** that you want to achieve.

Comment: made the questions more clearer

Comment: do you have `perl` installed on your SunOS box?    while this should be possible to do in awk,  it's much easier in perl because perl has `stat()` built-in, while awk doesn't.   The basic problem you're running into here is that Linux uses GNU versions of standard utils, while SunOS doesn't....which brings up another option: install the GNU tools onto your SunOS box - most or all are available as pre-compiled binary packages (they may already be installed, and you only need to refer to them by the correct PATH)

Comment: `it is not working` is the least useful of all problem descriptions. When **anything** in your life is not working and you want someone to help you to get it working, you need to tell them in what way it's not working. In this case - wrong output, no output, core dump, error messages, something else? What happens if you include a shebang at the top - `#!/bin/env bash`? What makes you think an awk script would be appropriate for this task?

Answer (score 1):

As replacement for stat you can use the following perl oneliner:

`perl -e 'print((stat("/tmp/a"))[10])'`

To workaround the current date you can use the `touch` command to create a temporary file and read the modification timestamp from the temp file like:

```
touch /tmp/currtime
CURRTIME=$(perl -e 'print((stat("/tmp/currtime"))[10])')
FILETIME=$(perl -e 'print((stat("/path/to/log"))[10])')
DIFFTIME=$(($CURRTIME - $FILETIME))
echo "Time difference is $DIFFTIME seconds"
#cleanup
rm /tmp/currtime
```

The reference about the perl stat() command can be found at: https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html

Comment: thanks a lot Lambert

Answer (score 0):

If the version of `date` on your SunOS system
doesn’t support the `+%s` argument,
then using `awk` to fix *that*, while not impossible, is impractical.

Does `stat filename -c %Y` work? 
If it doesn’t, you’re pretty much out of luck. 
If it does, you can use it to get the current time:

```
tmpfile="/tmp/apache_test$$"
if [ -e "$tmpfile" ]
then
    printf "%s exists; that’s odd.\n" "$tmpfile"
    exit
fi
if ! { touch "$tmpfile"  &&  CURTIME=$(stat "$tmpfile" -c %Y)  &&  rm "$tmpfile";}
then
    printf "Something went wrong.\n"
    exit
fi
```

If your version of bash doesn’t support `[ -e filename ]`,
then use `-f` instead.

P.S. You should quote all your variables:

```
FILETIME1=$(stat "$LOG" -c %Y)
TIMEDIFF1=$(expr "$CURTIME" – "$FILETIME1")
```

Comment: stat filename -c %Y work? 
no it didnt work

Comment: if you know any other commands, please let me know, i  just need a workaorund for these two commands